# CSS triangle arrow menu active item

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to put an arrow-up by using "pure" CSS on my active items menu. Problem, I have a weird output.
here my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/2pTwv/). Do you know how to resolve it ?

```
    #cssmenu li.active a {
   /* display: inline;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00b8fd;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;*/
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;

    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This is what you need - http://www.css3shapes.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the arrow is going to be as wide as the `li` that it describes. The best way to do something like this is to use a css pseudo element. What you are looking at is something like:

```
#cssmenu li.active a:before {
    content: ' ';
    width: 0px; 
    height: 10px; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Best of luck!

**Updated Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/XLfcY/

Comment: Hi drew_w, thanks for your exemple. I wanted to know if it is possible to have the arrow below the item instead of having at the top ?

Comment: I added, position:absolute; bottom:20px; at the end of #cssmenu li.active a:before. Sounds clean as solution ?

Comment: You can use that or you can use a `position:relative` instead - either works - just depends on what you are looking for. The result with relative is: http://jsfiddle.net/XLfcY/1/

Comment: super Drew_w. Thanks so much for answer and your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

for the pure css arrow

Comment: Hey Arun, is that possible to adapt your div solution with my menu/jquery structure ?

Answer (score 0):

The arrow at the bottom as you asked

```
position: relative;
top: 60px;
```

here the fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/suriyag/HwcTn/1/